# How to make your div stick to the page even when resolution of the window changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my div to scroll down as i scroll my window,its happening but when i change the resolution of the window its position shifts

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('#sticker').offset().top; 
    var stickyNav = function() { 
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('#sticker').addClass('effect');  
        } else {  
            $('#sticker').removeClass('effect');   
        }  
    };
});
```

// in css file

```
.effect
{
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  
    left: 783px;  
    top: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a proper HTML and CSS code with jsFiddle link?

Comment: can you share it in jsfiddle?

Comment: you set the fixed left position(783px), this position should be calculated based in the window size

Comment: also as you are setting a high number for left, i assume that you want this to be in the right side of the page... so it is better to use the right property instead of the left in the css

Comment: this is the link http://jsfiddle.net/4WTuQ/

Comment: @fmofdos even doing that there is no change when the resolution is changed

Answer (score 4):

Basically screen resolution independent thing is position fixed

if you have

```
<div class="asd"></div>
```

and you want to fix this div
css :

```
.asd{position:fixed; top:0;}
```

In your case you may have forgotten . in your css. "." defines class

```
.effect
{
position: fixed;  
    width: 100%;  
    left: 783px;  
    top: 0px;  

 }
```

Comment: i am able to get the effect but i am facing problem when the resolution of the window is changed, when resolution is more div is shifting towards right and left when resolution is less,the effect which i want is not resolution compatible

Comment: define left: 0 and min-width

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `position:fixed;` property in CSS to make that div fixed depending to the browser's window size (but the div's size won't change for you).

For responsiveness you can try the value of `top, left, right, bottom` as percentage.

I'm not absolutely sure about what you mean but you can try `position:absolute;` if you don't want the position to depend on the window's size but depends on the parent's div.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this effect?

[Mashable floating effect example with jQuery](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/mashable-floating-effect-example-with-jquery/)

Comment: i am able to get the effect but i am facing problem when the resolution of the window is changed, when resolution is more div is shifting towards right and left when resolution is less,the effect which i want is not resolution compatible